# Submitting a form in Iframe by Jquery and get the returned value

Tags: jquery, forms, iframe

Im having a webpage with an iframe with form in it. I want to submit the form and get the result. How can i do it with jquery?

```
<iframe src ="html_intro.asp" width="100%" height="300">
  <form action="submit.php">
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  </form>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#iframe_id').contents().find('form')[0].submit();
```

It is assumed that your are NOT hosting other domain in your iframe.

Answer (score 0):

If the iframe is hosted on a domain different than the parent domain you cannot manipulate it with javascript. To submit the form from within the iframe you could use the [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) method:

```
$('#yourFormId').submit();
```